An exercise about double covers
I am trying to solve exercise 2.1 in Voisin's Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry on double covers. The setup is this: $X$ is a complex manifold and $L$ is a holomorphic line bundle such that $K^{\otimes 2} = L$ for some holomorphic line bundle $K$. For $\sigma$ a nonzero section of $L$, let $\Sigma$ denote the image of $\sigma$. Let $\varphi: K \to L$ be the map defined by $(x, \tau) \mapsto (x, \tau^2)$, $R \subseteq X$ the vanishing locus of $\sigma$. Show that $Y = \varphi^{-1}(\Sigma)$ is smooth if and only if $R$ is smooth.
Given that the only criterion for the existence of smooth structures I know comes from pulling back submanifolds via submersions, I assume that I have to show that $R$ is locally a regular level set if and only if $\varphi_\ast$ is surjective (onto the tangent space of $\Sigma$) at the points of $Y$. I am confused how to do this, since it seems that at any point $x \in R$, the differential of $\varphi$ at $(x, 0) \in K$ has image generated by $\partial/\partial z_1, \ldots, \partial/\partial z_n$, where $z_1, \ldots, z_n$ are any local holomorphic coordinates of $X$ around $x$. However, in a trivialization of $L$ along $X$, we see that if $R$ is a regular level set, so that $\sigma'(x) = \partial \sigma/\partial z(x) \ne 0$, then the tangent space of $\Sigma$ is generated by the elements $\partial/\partial z_i + \sigma'(x) (\partial/\partial w)$, where $w$ is the line bundle coordinate. What am I doing wrong?
